# save data from a query in a model using jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

good afternoon i have a query, how could i save the values of a query in a model or class using jdbctemplate.

this is my code:

```
RequestMapping(value= "/formobligatorio/{pidm}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<FormPerson> grupoCodf(@PathVariable Long pidm) {
      int codf = 0;
      LinkedList<Integer> codFormsOblig = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> codfoblig = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String query=" select p.codigo_uzgtformularios from UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA p,UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS f where p.spriden_pidm =" + pidm + "and p.codigo_uzgtformularios = f.codigo_uzgtformularios and (  p.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='N' or f.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='S' or f.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='M' )  ORDER BY codigo_UZGTFORMULARIOS ASC";
        codfoblig = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query,Integer.class);
        for (int u = 0; u < codfoblig.size(); u++) {
            codf = codfoblig.get(u);
            codFormsOblig.add(codf);
        }
        System.out.println("codFormsOblig "+codFormsOblig);
```

// Here is my problem the codFormsOblig has 2 values, therefore the query below is going to be executed 2 times with different results, and those 2 results I need to save it in my model or FormPerson class.

```
    for (int u = 0; u <codFormsOblig.size (); u ++) {
    String query1 = "SELECT CODIGO_UZGTFORMULARIOS, UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO FROM UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS where UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO = 1 AND codigo_uzgtFormularios =" + codFormsOblig.get (u) + "AND UZGTFORMULARIOS_DE = CODE"
                     
         // I don't know what type of jdbctemplate to use , queryforobject, queryforlist or any other that will allow me to save the values of the fields in the model
;
           List <FormPerson> cod = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject (query1, FormPerson.class);

                         return code;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.

https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

Also, you need a space in this query

```
    String query1 = "SELECT CODIGO_UZGTFORMULARIOS, UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO FROM
 UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS where UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO = 1 AND codigo_uzgtFormularios =" +
 codFormsOblig.get (u) + "AND UZGTFORMULARIOS_DE = CODE"
```

if you have a class

```
class FormPerson {

  private String name;

  private String value;

}
```

you will need to use aliases in SQL

`SELECT CODIGO_UZGTFORMULARIOS as name, UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO as value`

The main things you need to learn

1. How to format the code.
2. How to give names to variables.